# Conditioning with External Drift Kriging using GSTools (and Pykrige...?)

Tags: python, kriging, geostatistics

I want to impute missing data on abortion rates of US-Counties. I´m comparing different Methods, one of them is Kriging. I used Pykrige for External Dirft Kriging:

```
def Kriging_with_SGS(df, variable, kriged_var, variogram, lags, drifts=None):
    interpolation_points = df[~df[variable].isnull()]
    interpolation_points.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    known_x = interpolation_points.geometry.centroid.x.values
    known_y = interpolation_points.geometry.centroid.y.values
    values = interpolation_points[variable].values
    external_drifts = []

    if drifts is not None:
        
        for drift in drifts:
            if drift in interpolation_points.columns:
                external_drift = interpolation_points[drift].values
                external_drifts.append(external_drift)
            else:
                print(f"The drift variable '{drift}' is missing.")

    if drifts:
        uk_all = UniversalKriging(
            known_x,
            known_y,
            values,
            variogram_model=variogram,
            drift_terms=["point_log"],
            point_drift=external_drifts if external_drifts else None,
            enable_plotting=True,
            nlags=lags,
            verbose=True
        )
        
    else:
        uk_all = UniversalKriging(
            known_x,
            known_y,
            values,
            variogram_model=variogram,
            enable_plotting=True,
            nlags=lags,
            verbose=True
        )

    df[kriged_var] = uk_all.execute(
        'points',
        df.geometry.centroid.x.values,
        df.geometry.centroid.y.values
    )[0]
```

With this code I managed to get the kriging results for the Counties which have missing values in the target variable. But I have the feeling, that I´m loosing to much variance in the far field. Therefore I want to include conditioning in my method:

```
def cond_krig(df, variable, iterations, drift):
    # create a df with only those values which exist:
    interpolation_points = df[~df[variable].isnull()]
    interpolation_points.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    known_x = interpolation_points.geometry.centroid.x.values
    known_y = interpolation_points.geometry.centroid.y.values
    
    cond_val = interpolation_points[variable].values
    
    # define the grid with all points that I have
    all_x = df.geometry.centroid.x.values 
    all_y = df.geometry.centroid.y.values

    
    ext_drift = interpolation_points[drift].values 
    grid_drift = df[drift].values
    
    model = gs.Matern(dim=2, 
                      var=0.09, 
                      len_scale=11284.23, 
                      nugget=0, 
                      nu=0.20)  

    krig = gs.krige.ExtDrift(model = model, 
                             cond_pos = (known_x, known_y), 
                             cond_val = cond_val, 
                             ext_drift = ext_drift)
    
    krig.unstructured([all_x, all_y], ext_drift=grid_drift)
    
    cond_srf = gs.CondSRF(krig)  
    
    cond_srf.set_pos([all_x, all_y], 
                     "unstructured")

    seed = gs.random.MasterRNG(20170519)
    
    for i in range(iterations):
        cond_srf(seed=seed(), store=[f"f{i}", False, False])
        print("___")
        print(i)
        print("___")
        
    fields = [cond_srf[f"f{i}"] for i in range(iterations)]
    
    filtered_df["ensemble mean"] = np.mean(fields, axis=0)
    filtered_df["kriged field"] = cond_srf.krig.field
```

I´m getting: `Value Error:Krige: wrong number of ext. drift values.` Thus I have two questions:

1.) What am I doing wrong in the second code, I provided? I know that I can make some fine-tuning with latlon and other parameters but there seems to be a substential error in my code.

2.) Is it possible to use the kriging model from Pykrige for conditioning? Something along these lines:

```
krig = uk_all.execute(
    'points',
    df.geometry.centroid.x.values,
    df.geometry.centroid.y.values
)[0]

    
cond_srf = gs.CondSRF(krig)  
cond_srf.set_pos([df.geometry.centroid.x.values, 
                  df.geometry.centroid.y.values], 
                 "unstructured")
```

I´m happy about any answer or advice. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record

This was answered here: https://github.com/GeoStat-Framework/GSTools/discussions/324

TL;DR:

The crucial part is, that `ext_drift=ext_drift_all` needs to be added to the arguments when calling `cond_srf` for the target locations.

Since it is an external drift, it needs to be provided at the target grid beforehand.